# Every symmetric operator is closable

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T:D(T)\to H$ be a symmetric operator. How can I prove that $T$ is closable??
Is there a self adjoint closed operator that extends $T$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 2007 and Math 1995 are the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :
Show that, if $U_n$ is a sequence in $D(T)$ such that, for some l ∈ H, we have $U_n$ →0 and $T(U_n) →l$ ,then $l=0$.